# Accessing transmission web interface not allowed

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie

When trying to access my Raspberry Pi 2 with transmission-daemon up, I get an error `Unauthorized IP Address`.

In accordance with the [manual](https://github.com/transmission/transmission/wiki/Editing-Configuration-Files), I've edited `/etc/transmission-daemon/settings.json`:

```
{
...
"rpc-authentication-required": true,
"rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0",
"rpc-enabled": true,
"rpc-password": "mychain",
"rpc-port": 9091,
"rpc-url": "/transmission/",
"rpc-username": "transmission",
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192,192.168.*.*",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,
...
}
```

I edited the JSON file with the daemon stopped and after saving the changes, I restarted the daemon.

I still got this error:

```
403: Forbidden

Unauthorized IP Address.

Either disable the IP address whitelist or add your address to it.

If you're editing settings.json, see the 'rpc-whitelist' and 'rpc-whitelist-enabled' entries.

If you're still using ACLs, use a whitelist instead. See the transmission-daemon manpage for details.
```

Comment: I think you may have a typo in the "rpc-whitelist" entry, I suspect it should be "127.0.0.1,192.168.*.*" - 127.0.0.1 is "localhost" i.e. the local machine where the software is running, and 192.168.x.x. is the set of Class C IP addresses reserved for LAN (which no self-respecting Modem/Router should pass out onto the WAN/Internet) - the first "192" has to be an erroneous entry IMHO.

Comment: Soory,, i put "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192,192.168.*.*", but corrrect it's "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192.168.*.*",. My LAN it's 192.168.1.0/24. Problen now it's other.

Comment: Is it working now or not?  BTW when writing comments it is worth it to take the time to check the spelling of your words is correct before you click "Add Comment" - you have plenty of time to write the comment - but it is only possible to fix smelling errors if you click on "edit" for a very short time afterwards - all in all it is better to get it right before you click to post the comment... 8-P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDITED & SOLVED

```
Correct line
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192.168.*.*",
Incorrect line
"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,192,192.168.*.*",
```

Comment: rpc-whitelist will also accept whitespace as well as commas:

"rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1 192.168.*.* ",

Answer (score 7):

A common mistake I did is mistaking

```
rpc-whitelist
```

with

```
rpc-host-whitelist
```

The one to modify is

```
"rpc-whitelist": "192.168.*.* 127.0.0.1",
"rpc-whitelist-enabled": true,
```

Note that to configure the Transmission daemon, it *mustn't* be running: Stop the daemon, edit the config, then restart the daemon. Otherwise your changes to the config file will be silently ignored and overwritten.